# datastage client login issue

Tags: etl, datastage

Could anybody please help me to resolve the issue to logon the datastage designer installed on my personal computer's ? (I access Datastage from My Computer VMWare-->Windows Server 2003 --->Datastage)

Keep on getting below error When I am trying to logon.

Failed to authenticate the current user (admin) against the selected domain.
Could not connect to server[admin] on port [9080]

Below are the things that I have to figure out the issue.

1) I did TELNET  9080
got connected refused message. Not sure whether this could be the issue or not.

2)I even tried to give other listening port in register-server.xml but no luck

please help me.

Comment: Is your service tier (WebSphere) started?

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall. And also I don't know what port did you chose in the installation but if I'm correct the default port is 8090 not 9080

Comment: WebSphere's default http port is 9080

Answer (score 0):

Did you gone through the presentation on datastage client log in failures?? There may be multiple root-causes.Please check the link [Datastage client log in issues presentation by IBM](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/imv1r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.iea.infosphere_is/infosphere_is/8.5/ProbDeter/Client_Login_Failures/player.html) ..

Answer (score 0):

You did not set the engine credentials for the user,
please follow the below link, it explains how to set up engine credentials.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/imv1r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.iea.infosphere_is/infosphere_is/8.5/configuration/BasicDSusers/player.html